# Reverse stack into file

Tags: c++, stack, fstream

I need to create a program that reads a file, pushes the content into a stack, then writes that content in reverse to another file. I don't understand why my file isn't being found or outputting. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>



int main() {

std::stack<char>charStack;

std::fstream file;
std::fstream revFile;
std::string fileName;

std::cout << "Enter the name of the file you want to open." << std::endl;
std::cin >> fileName;
file.open(fileName);

std::cout << "Adding input from file to stack." << std::endl;

char ch;
file >> std::noskipws;

while (file >> ch) {

    std::cout << ch;
    charStack.push(ch);
}
file.close();

revFile.open("newFile.txt");

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Reversing stack and writing to file." << std::endl;

while (!charStack.empty()) {

    char i = charStack.top();
    revFile << i;
    charStack.pop();
}

revFile.close();
revFile.open("newFile.txt");

std::cout << "Here is the original file reversed." << std::endl;

std::string line;
    if (revFile.is_open()) {
            while (std::getline(revFile, line)) {
                    std::cout << line;
            }
            revFile.close();
    }
    else std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;


revFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I'm unsure if I need to add an empty .txt file to write to or if this should generate one for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should create one for you. You should learn to use a debugger to debug your programs. You can also try using print statements to print out the values of variables or creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't need to know about the code pushing the stuff into the stack and popping it back out if your problem is just about being able to read or write to files.

Comment: I have used the debugger. All it says is "cannot find or open the PDB file."

Comment: @KennethFreeman: There could be a lot of reason as the user is entering the file name. Make sure the file name is in the same dir of the exe file of your source code or enter the full path using \\ like: c:\\temp and it might be case-sensitive to. Try with hard coded file first. I tries your code and it is working to me. but the out put file needs more work for the newlines. other than that it works.

Comment: The issue isn't the original file. It, for some reason, is the one being created for the reversed content.

Comment: I made a mistake. Since the default constructor for `fstream` includes `ios_base::in` for the mode, it won't actually create a file for you. Like Shadi said, I tested your code and there doesn't seem to be any problems other than some minor issues with newlines.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions on the output folder?

Comment: I do not have a file in the project for the newFile.txt. Is this were my issue is? I thought that it would generate that file itself. What do you mean it needs work for the newlines?

Comment: It should generate the file itself, but it has to have file system permissions to do so. usually this should not be the issue but may be. Also try restarting the machine may be your IDE is stuck at some place. it happened to me once. What I can say, **the problem is not in the code.**

Comment: @Shadi It actually won't generate a file for you, with the reasons in my previous comment. Note that when I said "default constructor", it should have been the `open()` function if you don't provide the argument for the mode.

Comment: @Fei Xiang: What do you mean won't. It = the program. the code should generate the output file and it did. I am afraid We are not talking about the same thing or I'm missing your point. excuse my English.

Comment: @Shadi I [tested it myself](https://pastebin.com/0s2eZy6k). `is_open()` is false, and no file is created, unless you change the open mode from the default `ios_base::in | ios_base::out` to only `ios_base::out`. Note that the OP is using `fstream` here, not `ofstream`.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the file opening statements to be:

```
revFile.open("newFile.txt",ios::out); //for output
```

and

```
revFile.open("newFile.txt",ios::in); //for input
```

other than that, you just need to correct this line to get a correct printing of the file contents after reversing.

```
  std::cout << line;
```

Make it:

```
  std::cout << line << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I really need to practice with using files more. I tried doing (std::ios::in|std::ios::out) early on when I initialized revFile, but that didn't work. This does.